# Text in quotation marks in a question's title doesn't appear on the Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

E.g. this question entitled [Translation of “Glasshole”](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/11015/839) appears like this on my Android:

[image: Translation of... what?]

I use Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.2.
The application version is 1.0.43.

Comment: Same phone, Android 4.4.2, and the title is shown normally. Upgrade maybe...

Comment: Repro on Galaxy S5, 4.4.2, newest version of app.

Comment: Issue still present.

Comment: No repro on Nexus 4, Android 4.4.4, app ver 1.0.43. Title shown normally.